# how to backup with a unique file name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

i am trying to take a backup by creating a job in sql server agent using stored procedure. i am able to take the backup but each time it overwrites my previous backup file. i want my backup should create a different file with unique file name using date. how can I achieve this. below is my code, any help would be appreciated

```
DECLARE @backupfilename VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(1000)

SET @backupfilename='C:\SqlBackups\AdventureWorks\Full\backup_' + CONVERT (VarChar, GetDate(), 112) + '.bak'
SET @path = 'BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2012 TO  DISK = ''' + @backupfilename + ''''

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep  
    @job_name = 'BackupDatabase',   
    @step_name = 'Weekly Full Backup',   
    @subsystem = 'TSQL',   
    @command = @path;
```

Comment: just change `112` in your `CONVERT` statement to `126`.  This will be a full timestamp that includes milliseconds.

Comment: i have tried that as well, that replaces my previous file with new date and time. but i dont want my previous file to get deleted

Comment: how frequent are you executing the backup ? With you current query, if you execute it once a day it will generate a `backupfilename` for each day and will not overwrite your previous day backup.